# Azure DataFactory self hosted integration runtime is now shown in portal

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a self-hosted integration runtime using powershell :

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -Name $selfHostedIntegrationRuntimeName -Type SelfHosted -Description "selfhosted IR description"
```

But when I check the Azure Datafactory portal and then select Integration Runtime I can't see it. When I create via. portal it's visible to me.
I can check its status in Powershell it exists there.

```
 Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -Name $selfHostedIntegrationRuntimeName -Status
```

I was even able to register it and I see its status is online but nothing is shown in the portal.

Is there any reason it's not shown?

Comment: Double-check whether you didn't confuse the target name of ADF. Maybe via PowerShell, you deployed it to another ADF...?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
In Portal it's showing by default from master branch.
I needed to switch to live mode to see all integrations.

Comment: Do you know how to get the IR to show up in Git? ADF is telling me that I can't use the Integration Runtime in Live mode since I have Git enabled, but then I also can't use it in Git mode because it's not visible.